# the .m3u8 video being downloaded converted to mp4 result in trouble

Tags: ffmpeg, download, codec

why did the .m3u8 video being downloaded converted outright to mp4 result in lower resolution quality?
It's anyway either done by vlc or ffmpeg cli

Please one expert solve it to be got the same good resolution quality as what browser page shows?

EDIT

```
$ sudo ffmpeg -i 'https://proxy-11.sg1.dailymotion.com/sec(vlh-KpwGb8HUr2KugsbYOZgrMqEUsCk-Wr4rEY_5AqbneuzjuA3qznTv3J7Sl5084vG7LbkiwnlnMin5-vwmgiHUl-fZHe3jBg9cEpO_AKE)/video/411/277/413772114_mp4_h264_aac_l2.m3u8' -c:av copy -f mp4 nature
```

just got it at Chrome network tool, see how a browser show it https://www.dailymotion.com/video/x6ucklu

Comment: Need to see your ffmpeg command and the complete log to be able to understand the problem (assuming you're using ffmpeg).

Comment: Your video is of low quality (originally 480p), and horizontally flipped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `ffmpeg` log will show that the input is only 176x108.

Use a different M3U8 URL that provides the resolution and quality you want.

Comment: How does it produce multiple m3u8 files? the latest would always be the highest?

Comment: @nikmat Your M3U8 only provided one resolution. If you input a M3U8 that provides  multiple sizes then ffmpeg will choose the biggest one by default.